# Set storage class on upload

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

Currently I upload files to my bucket with this code:

```
function upload_file_to_gcs($source, $des) {
    global $gcs;
    $bucketName = 'example';
    $file = fopen($source, 'r');
    $bucket = $gcs->bucket($bucketName);
    try {
        $result = $bucket->upload($file, [
            'name' => $des,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/zip'
        ]);
    }
}
```

But now I want to set the Storage Class, this file should be uploaded to. How can I do that? 
In the Amazon AWS I was able to simply set the storage class like:

```
$result = $s3->putObject([
    'Bucket' => 'example',
    'Key'    => 'folder/'.$des,
    'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD_IA',     // <--- Simple options command
    'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
    'SourceFile'   => $source,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/zip'
]);
```

But how can I do this with the Google Storage? I couldn't find any option within the documentation:
http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.31.1/storage/bucket?method=upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
$result = $bucket->upload($file, [
        'name' => $des,
        'metadata' => [ 'storageClass' => 'regional' ]
    ]);
```